Use Isolate Origins in conjunction with process-per-site

Electron 23.1.1
Chrome: 110.0.5481.104

I have an Electron Desktop app which reacts to certain events and opens up new Browser windows for each new event.
For performance reasons, we have added process-per-site so that new windows don't have to create a new renderer process.
The apps loads two different urls in the Browser Windows:

somedomain.xy.com - This is a Static Window
localhost.xy.com:74125. - This is the url used to open new windows reacting to events.

As I can understand, the above 2 urls come under same site because of xy.com. This is leading to have one shared process for all the windows.
I wanted to have a separate process for the Static window and another process which houses all the windows reacting to events. This is to prevent any crash jeopradizing all the renderer windows.
I have tried
app.commandLine.appenSwitch('isolateOrigins', 'https://localhost.xy.com:74125')
and also
app.commandLine.appenSwitch('isolate-origins', 'https://localhost.xy.com:74125')
But, unable to see the process separation.

Have you tried site-per-process instead. Also, I would add everything you want to isolate even if they are the same domain, i.e. ```app.commandLine.appendSwitch('isolate-origins', 'https://localhost.xy.com:74125,https://somedomain.xy.com');


See here for more info: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation/

Thank you, with Site-per-process, it creates additional processes for every new window I create for localhost. Creation of new process adds some delay which is not expected by the app. Also, I have tried adding both the sites for isolate-origins, don't see the benefit still.

I found that your issue is most likely related to your port 74125. It is not in spec of a valid port range.
When you add a new manual site isolation entry in chrome://flags/#isolate-origins, you will notice that any entries with invalid URLs are stripped after taking effect. The same occurs when using flags.
Try using a different port and make sure, as @djmonki mentioned, to add both URLs in a list to enforce separation on both sites. In the end you should see a separation in chrome://process-internals/#site-isolation

The port I had added here was a dummy port, the actual port I use is 10128. On your answer, I in fact tried changing the port to 4353 as well but still all the renderers are in the same process. I have tried adding all the origins in isolate-origins switch. That doesn't work either.

A shame, i thought i was onto something here. From what you provided i do believe it should be working. Maybe you will have to open a ticket at chromium for some help. I‘m looking forward to see what your solution will be in the end.

Just out of curiosity, do you maybe have any conflicting flags before/after you call isolate-origins or do did you set anything related to CORS?

Apart from process-per-site and isolate-origins, the other chromium switches I have are ignore-certificate-errors and no-sandbox While launching the window on localhost, I had webSecurity to false (this takes care of ignoring  CORS). I removed no-sanbox and turned webSecurity to true. Still the same result.

I will try isolating the issue of something I am doing wrong in a fresh app without much logic and which just creates these windows along with the switches in discussion
